# WSOS GREG : redirect to url not supporting offset

Tags: wso2-governance-registry

Using Registry 5.1  - Any attempt to add a wsdl, displays a depreciated message, 'use https://localhost:9445/publisher', but any attempt to use this url fails because the subsequent login screen doesn't seem to know about the port 'offset' feature - basically I suspect there is a bug when Registry is not deployed on the default port.

```
https://localhost:9443/publisher/acs?loginStatus=true 
i.e. its using wrong port should be + 1
```

Possibly finger trouble? should this work & I'm missing something?

Comment: Solved: Restored registry to offset 0, and all links work as expected. 50+% confident of an offset related bug.

Comment: Port offset is working as expected in GReg 5.1.0. Could you double check or let us know the reproducing steps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access publisher and store after port offset, you need to change the content of the `<GREG_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/sso-idp-config.xml`. You need to specify the correct port number in that file. Please refer to the following config; here port offset of 3 is used:

```
<AssertionConsumerService>https://localhost:9446/publisher/acs</AssertionConsumerService>
```